# How to assign task to User from Look up field in Workflow?

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, lookup

I'm using a workflow rule where in the workflow actions I need to create a new task and assign it to a user form a custom lookup field. The problem is that in the Assign To Field ,once you click on the button with the magnifier there is no option to pickup the user from the lookup custom field. The are only three options :

1. User
2. Role
3. Group

To me the only way to assign a task to a user from a custom lookup field is by creating an apex trigger.

What I want to achieve is that when a checkbox field is checked it has to fire a process where new task is assigned to a user from the custom lookup field.
Could you please advise how this can be achieved in Salesforce by also providing code example.

Comment: I believe that process builder could do this.   Have not tested specifically this scenario but it's well within the norm for other things I have done with it.

Comment: agree with gorav; Process Builder has much more flexibility that Workflow in the values you can set for the Task object - workflow offers only limited dials to turn.  Please use [edit] on your post with a Process Builder flow (and remove the Workflow bits) if you get stuck